# Filter Data Based on Column Selection

Tags: google-sheets

Working in Google Sheets I'm making a gradebook. In the gradebook there are different assignment types that have different weights which can be chosen from the drop down. I would like to...

1. Average like assignment (there will be 3 values)
2. Weigh them appropriately (0.1 for baseline, 0.7 for Critical, 0.2 for accelerated.)
3. Add all the values together into 1 grade percentage.
4. Display them on grade report sheet for appropriate student.

I would like for this to be dynamic, so that if I change the assignment type (or any other values) the grade will change appropriately.

my MWE can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KPe2jSmlplz9RMbfna17UNwWq6AU_pcsCtu61s0nwVU/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AverageIf function will do what you need. So code like:

```
=averageif(B$3:G$3,"Baseline",B4:G4)
```

sitting next to your student in the 4th row (this is draggable, so row will update) that checks against values of assignment type in your 3rd row (3 is fixed by the dollar sign, so draggable) will accomplish your goal 1.

Once you do that for each of the averages, you can define one more column as `=0.1*baseline avg+0.7*critical+0.2*accelerated`
[not exactly that, I am pseudocoding] to achieve your other 3 objectives, I think.

Comment: see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z5NBjwQ8edN-ssNDP72p2uP750QvqESR1ND2GUUOVbo/edit?usp=sharing for what I believe is a minimal working solution for your MWE

Comment: I had to tweak it a little bit to grab the information from the other sheet. But it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to add another conditional, it seems to work with nested if statements, but I guess this is more complicated and it's not working.

`=averageif(B$3:G$3,"Baseline",B4:G4,iferror(1/0,0.1))`

Basically, I'm trying to let the code to not count that weighted value if it does not exist.

Comment: So you will need to think about how to count -- do you need to reweight? But to avoid that unsightly DIV/0 error, you can wrap things in an if as follows: =IF(COUNTIF($B3:$G3,"Baseline")=0,"",averageif($B$3:$G$3,"Baseline",$B4:$G4))

Comment: I got it working with this. `iferror(AVERAGEIFS(B4:G4,B$3:G$3,"Baseline")*2.5,0)` this way if there's a `#DIV/0!` error it inserts a 0.

Comment: nice. the above would also do so if you wanted, just replace "" with 0. Also, probably it would be slightly better to replace "Baseline" to a reference to the sheet where you define the categories (that way if you change the name, it's automatic elsewhere -- and you can then drag the formula over for other categories). You could do the same in the column headers. But these are minor ideas. Way to go getting it to work how you want!